# How to output sas format as proc format syntax?

Tags: sas

I have created a format based on a dataset. Now I want to store this format as a value-list as part of the proc format syntax in my sas program. Is there a way to accomplish this?

The reason for doing this is that I often need to make tables which group the country background of people into groups similar to continents. Until now this has been done by joining the data using country code as key variable with another dataset which contain a continents variable, and then applying a format $continents on the continents variable.

I want to be able to skip this join operation by making a format for continents that takes country codes as input values. I also want this format to be stored in the syntax file which produces the tables and not in a format catalog. Since the world has a lot of countries, writing this format manually seems prone to error.

Comment: I'm a bit curious as to why you'd want to do that?

Comment: I frequently do this sort of thing using excel of all things... Export the dataset to Excel. Then just do something like: `=concatenate(A1,"='",A2,"'")`. Then copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guide, hasn't been tested with every scenario e.g. numeric, character & informat or multi-label/picture formats.

```
/* Create a dummy format */
data dummyfmt ;
  retain fmtname 'DUMMY' type 'N' ;
  do i = 1 to 10 ;
    start = i ;
    label = repeat(byte(round(ranuni(0) * (122 - 97 + 1),1) + 96),10) ;
    if i = 10 then hlo = 'O' ;
    output ;
  end ;
run ;
proc format cntlin=dummyfmt ; run ;


/* Dump the format back out to a dataset */
proc format cntlout=dump library=work ;
  select dummy ;
run ;

proc print heading=H ; run ;

/* Write out to log... */
data _null_ ;
  set dump end=eof ;

  if _n_ = 1 then do ;
    put "proc format ;" ;
    if type = 'N' then put "  value " fmtname ;
    if type = 'C' then put "  value $" fmtname ;
    if type = 'I' then put "  invalue " fmtname ;
  end ;

  if hlo = 'O' then do ;
    if type in('N' 'C') then put "  other = '" label +(-1) "'" ;
    if type = 'I' then put " other = " label ;
  end ;
  else do ;
    if type in('N' 'C') then put "  " start " = '" label +(-1) "'" ;
    if type = 'I' then put "  " start " = " label ;
  end ;

  if eof then do ;
    put "  ;" ;
    put "run ;" ;
  end ;
run ;
```

You may need to modify the above depending on your format, especially if there's ranges involved. The SEXCL and EEXCL columns would then be relevant.

```
/* Example output (from Log Window) */
proc format ;
  value DUMMY
  1  = 'bbbbbbbbbbb'
  2  = 'hhhhhhhhhhh'
  3  = 'ttttttttttt'
  4  = 'fffffffffff'
  5  = 'sssssssssss'
  6  = 'bbbbbbbbbbb'
  7  = 'aaaaaaaaaaa'
  8  = 'ppppppppppp'
  9  = 'eeeeeeeeeee'
  other = 'wwwwwwwwwww'
  ;
run ;
```